# Trying to display data on gallery using dropdown and button it is showing only one id data

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Here what I am trying:

[image]

[image]

I try to Display data of particular date and breakfast to show and if it change to lunch from dropdown second then it should show lunch data, but it showing only one last match id data, i want to show all related data, related to particular date that is breakfast,lunch and dinner.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Apps you can handle this scenario more concisely.

The Gallery has an 'Items' property. You will only need to write the proper formula here, and there will be no need to use the dropdown .OnSelect properties, or the Load button.

Try a formula like this:

```
Filter(DietPlanDateZones,Zone = Dropdown2.Selected.Value, 'Diet Date' = DatePicker2.SelectedDate)
```

This will make the Gallery update itself dynamically whenever your dropdown or datepicker changes.

This training module might offer some help on [how this approach (declarative) and your approach (imperative) work in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/use-imperative-dev-techniques-powerapps-canvas-app/).